# QGIS Pipe Flow and Aerial Photo

Tags: qgis

I am completely new to QGIS and We had the survey pick for drainage pipes and pits. 
We have Upstream and Downstream invert level for each pipe.

Wondering if any one could help with step by step, set up for pipe flow direction with arrow showing on the pipe?

How to add layer with aerial photograph in the background for Western Australia region.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your photography georeferenced? If so drag it in from explorer. How do you have invert levels? Are they points, table... are your pipes 3d data?

Comment: Yes. The pipe has IL and has X,Y,Z for pit, Starting X,Y,Z to Ending X,Y,Z for pipes

Comment: It seems your data is 2d with Z (which is not 3d). Is there any chance you have access to ArcGis? This would be so much easier in arcpy... QGIS is my second fiddle (well, 3rd or 4th) and I'm not sure I understand enough about the API to come up with a solution without a lot of effort.